# Big picture notification in ice cream sandwitch

Tags: android, notifications

Its possible to show `jelly bean` `notification` (Big picture) in `ice cream sandwich` with the support library v11 update and `notificationcompat`?

Answer (score 2):

No, sorry.

`NotificationCompat` allows `BigPictureStyle` to *run* on older Android devices, but only by ignoring it. That means your code does not need to change for older devices, but you will not magically get the Jelly Bean capabilities.